# migration to iCloud sync causing crash

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm working on an iPhone app using SwiftUI that used to store data locally. Recently, I enabled iCloud sync. It's working as desired with all data imported/created after upgrading to the new version. However, when I create new data (a CoreData object) in the old version of the app and then upgrade to the new version, I get a crash when I try to access that data.

The control flow for the user is this: Upon launch after the upgrade, the user navigates to a view, which is a tableView list. When the user taps on a cell, it opens into a list of sound files (at this point, a crash could happen any time). Each cell represents a CoreData object that contains a list of fileURLS (these are just the last components of the url. File name and type. They are appended to the directory path when looking them up for playback). Importantly, you do not need to attempt to play a sound file in order to get a crash.

The error message I get in the console is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2809eec40'
```

The code below is used to migrate the sound files from the local container to iCloud. It's meant to run once per user, and is called upon launch in the AppDelegate. The crash happens even if there are no sound files, so I'm pretty sure it's not related. Also, you can sometimes play the files partially or all the way through before the crash occurs.

```
        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let iCloudPath = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")

        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: iCloudPath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            
            let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            
            do {
                let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentPath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
                
                if directoryContents.count == 0 {
                    // likely a first time user. The directory is empty and there is no need to delay.
                    completion(false)
                } else {
                    
                    if let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents"){
                        
                        for item in directoryContents {
                            
                            let originatingURL:URL = documentPath.appendingPathComponent(item.lastPathComponent)
                            let destinationURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(item.lastPathComponent)

                            do {
                                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: originatingURL, to: destinationURL)
                                
                                do {
                                    try FileManager().startDownloadingUbiquitousItem(at: destinationURL)
                                } catch{
                                    print("Error while downloading audio file \(error)")
                                }
                            } catch {
                                print("failed to move file from local container to iCloud container")
                            }
                        }
                        completion(true)
                    }
                }
                
            }catch {
                
                print("unable to get local container")
                completion(false)
            }

        } catch let error {
            print("Unable to create directory \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to tag this as `Swift` instead of `SwiftUI` since it doesn't involve any SwiftUI code

Comment: Good point. Thanks